# What character encoding is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, character-encoding

I am in a Rails application.

When I open a *.yml* file which stores all the localized Scandinavian characters, it shows some in " `K�ytt�j�` ", I would like to find out **what is the encoding** is this, but I am not sure how can I find the encoding name.

Does anyone knows how?? or any tools can help me to figure out the **encoding** method?

Comment: Paste the text in hex form if you want to know the encoding. In general, finnish uses UTF-8, ISO8859-1 or ISO8859-15 (or SF7 if you are dealing with very old data).

Comment: We have no way to figure out what it is. Can it be UTF8 or UTF16? If you see something like "I was K�ytt�j�" it is a multibyte encoding, probably UTF.

If you see something like "�a�c�d�x�e� �r" it can be UNICODE, 16 bit per characters.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding

Comment: @Mellon: if you are on *nix you can use enca.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca

Comment: @RageZ, but it does not support Scandinavian languages, isn't it, at least I didnot found.

Comment: @Mellon: it would tell you at least if it's UTF-8. If you already know what language it is you might want to try each encoding until the text seems ok

Answer (score 0):

`file --mime-encoding myfile.yml`